# How delete all variables available in python to free memory?

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management

I trying to find out a way to **free the memory** in my python script before start.

How can I delete all created variables in python to make **sure** the script have all memory available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gc.collect()` will release all unreferenced memory. (see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gc.html)

But to deliberately delete variables use [del](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=del#the-del-statement).  Keep in mind you'll need to do this for all variables.

```
myvar1 = 1
myvar2 = True
del myvar1
del myvar2
```